# How to connect a seat to a chair's frame from below?

Tags: repair, screws, chair

The chair has a relatively thin hard layer of wood (less than half an inch thick), over which there is the soft layer (cushion with a cover etc.). It used to have diagonally attached screws. Here's a very simplified drawing showing the diagonal holes for screws:

[image]

(The soft part cannot be removed.)

The holes in the hard layer have become too wide so the screws don't stay in place at all. But even if they did, I don't really like this method, since this means there are sharp points where a person is sitting. So adding L's like in the following drawing, while it is a solution, is one I'd like to avoid. Like this:

[image]

I was wondering, though, if there is a better way. Perhaps something rounded like this (on the left):

[image]

Or perhaps something like wall anchors ([like this one for example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08SBX1NQ5))   but these don't seem to be appropriate, so I mean something generally similar.

So what's a solution in a case like this?

Comment: Screws come in different lengths.  Get screws equal to the thickness of the wood/hard part, then with the thickness of the L, there should be no pointy to dig into skin.  Can also add washers between the screw head and the L to reduce length in the wood.

Comment: use flat head bolts from top

Comment: @crip659 `Get screws equal to the thickness of the wood/hard part` - That's why I wrote `relatively thin hard layer` - for the thick part of the screw to get there, the whole point will be in the soft part. In short - not practical.

Comment: @Traveler That means a person sitting on the chair will see those bolts (and also have less room on the chair). I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Use thicker screws and re-use the holes.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean That would mean also drilling those holes wider. That in itself isn't really that difficult, of course, but as I wrote, if possible, I'd like to use some different method in order to avoid the points unprotected under the cushion.

Comment: @ispiro under the cushion, you will not see or feel them

Comment: @ispiro Why would you need to drill it out? Just use one size thicker and a length that does not protrude into the seat.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean The holes in the chairs' legs are two narrow. As for `a length that does not protrude into the seat` - there is no such thing, the hard wooden part is around an 8th of an inch thick. If that. And screws don't reach their thickness that fast, the point will be in the cushion.

Comment: @ispiro   The thickness should be in the question.  It is quite important information.  At 1/8 I am wondering if it structural or just a covering for the soft part hiding extra wood supports.  I would not trust 1/8 wood to sit on.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks. I added it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Flat head bolts.

Insert from the top (under the soft cushion and screw from the bottom.

If you choose 1 inch size bolt head and 1/4 inch bolts that should hold it for long time and resist the stool movement.

Some drilling might be required

Example

[image: bolt]

Comment: As I wrote in the question `The soft part cannot be removed.`. However, it's true, of course, that `cannot` is not **absolutely unquestionably**. So perhaps this is the best option. I was hoping there'd be an **A HA!** solution. If non will be found, this might be the best option after all.

Comment: @ispiro  As I said, 1/8 is too thin to be the only wood support over the legs.  I would think it is hiding thicker wood supports.  Screwing legs to 1/8 is not good.  Screwing 1/8 to legs is better, so I doubt those screws you had, were screwing into the 1/8 wood, unless the chair came from a 5 and dime store on sale.